# Laravel 5.5 Login errors not showing up

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Here is my login.blade.php

```
@if(Session::get('errors')||count( $errors ) > 0)
   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <h1>{{ $error }}</h1>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Here is my LoginController.php:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => 'ERRORS',
        ]);
}
```

And here is my web.php (routes)

```
// I am customizing the login to do extra checks, 
// but I still need the basic auth scaffolding.
Auth::routes(); 
...
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  Route::view('/login', 'auth.login');
  Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
});
```

When I try to login with a bad user it **shows no errors** in the view, what am I doing wrong?

**Update**:
I've tried to change the login.blade.php, as @Seva Kalashnikov suggested, with no luck.
I've also tried @Akshay Kulkarni suggestion with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after a few hours I finally found it! I created a Laravel project from scratch and made a diff to find the culprit:

In *app/Http/Kernel.php*, make sure to get rid of the StartSession middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // <-- Remove this
];
```

Explanation: I had it there because I read that I had to put it as a middleware (if I wasn't using the `Route::group(['middleware' =>'web']` wrapper in my web.php), I think that I forgot it there. I think that putting it there **and** using the wrapper in web.php somehow truncate the error session before it gets to the view.

Answer (score 8):

Try to remove `Session::get('errors')` from your `if` statement in login.blade.php

```
@if(count( $errors ) > 0)
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
       <h1>{{ $error }}</h1>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

`ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware, which is provided by the web middleware group is responsible for `$error` view variable so it will always be defined ([link here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors))

[UPDATE]

And as @Ohgodwhy pointed, you need to use `@if ($errors->any())` [Example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

So in your case it will be:

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
       <h1>{{ $error }}</h1>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Here's the example from Laravel Basic Auth Views: https://github.com/drbyte/laravel-basic-auth-views/blob/master/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

Comment: and [here's an example from the documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors). it should be `$errors->any()`. the view message bag is always available.

Answer (score 2):

Put,

Auth::routes();

Inside middleware group.

Web middleware starts the session.
If you are writing any route outside that middleware group then you can not access the session.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Entrust (or maybe some other packages) and add its classes to `$routeMiddleware`, the problem can be deriving from that your subsequently added custom classes override the default Laravel classes.

The solution is to move your custom classes to the top of `$routeMiddleware` array.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. After a lot of digging here and there, I solved it by removing *\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::clas*s from *$middlewareGroups* of *'web'* in app\http\kernel.php.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // <-- Remove this
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

It is realted to @halfer's solution.